# Spring cloud kafka stream application terminates on exception

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-cloud-stream

I have simple spring cloud kafka stream application. The application terminates each time there is an exception and I'm unable to overwrite this behaviour. The desired outcome is incremental backoff when there are certain types of exceptions or to continue on other type of exceptions. I use `springCloudVersion - Hoxton.SR3` and `spring boot: 2.2.6.RELEASE`

application.yaml

```
spring:
 cloud:
   stream:
     binders.process-in-0:
         destination: test

     kafka:
       streams:
         binder:
           deserializationExceptionHandler: logAndContinue
           configuration:
             default.key.serde: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes$StringSerde
             default.value.serde: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes$StringSerde
```

Beans

```
@Bean
public java.util.function.Consumer<KStream<String, String>> process() {
    return input -> input.process(() -> new EventProcessor());
}

@Bean
public StreamsBuilderFactoryBeanCustomizer customizer() {
    return fb -> {
        fb.getStreamsConfiguration().put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_PRODUCTION_EXCEPTION_HANDLER_CLASS_CONFIG,
                ContinueOnErrorHandler.class);
    };
}
```

EventProcessor

```
public class EventProcessor implements Processor<String, String>, ProcessorSupplier<String, String> {

    private ProcessorContext context;

    @Override
    public void init(ProcessorContext context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void process(String key, String value) {

        throw new RuntimeException("Some exception");
    }

    @Override
    public void close() {

    }

    @Override
    public Processor<String, String> get() {
        return this;
    }
}
```

ContinueOnErrorHandler

```
public class ContinueOnErrorHandler implements ProductionExceptionHandler {
    @Override
    public ProductionExceptionHandlerResponse handle(ProducerRecord<byte[], byte[]> record, Exception exception) {
        return ProductionExceptionHandlerResponse.CONTINUE;
}

    @Override
    public void configure(Map<String, ?> configs) {
        //ignore
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The custom processor you are using from the consumer is throwing a `RuntimeException` in the `process` method. It is not caught by anything. When that exception is thrown, the application simply exits.

The production exception handler that you are using does not have any effect here since you are not producing anything here. `Consumer` does not produce anything. If you have a use case of producing something, you should switch to `java.util.funciton.Function` instead.

In order to fix the issue here, as you are processing the record in the custom processor (`EventProcessor`), if you get an exception, you should catch it and take appropriate actions. For e.g, here is a template:

```
        @Override
        public void init(ProcessorContext context) {
            this.context = context;
        }

        @Override
        public void process(String key, String value) {
            try {
                // start processing
                // exception thrown

            }
            catch (Exception e){
                // Take the appropriate action
            }
        }
```

This way, the application won't be terminated when the exception is thrown in the processor.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Is there a way to handle exception globally instead in the processor? I know that not every exception results in termination for example when connection to database is down and processor inserts the record, in this case application is not terminated. I tested that with postgresql.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by globally handling it. Other than handling deserialization exceptions on the inbound and serialization exceptions on the outbound, Kafka Streams doesn't provide any global exception mechanisms. You need to handle them within the application's logic.